# I dont know where the error is in this code

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Try

MySqlConn.Open()

```
        Dim Query = "Select * From venuesdb.cost where EventDate  >= ('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "') AND =< ('" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "')"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = Command
        SQLDataAdapter.Fill(DatabaseDatSet)
        Bindsource.DataSource = DatabaseDatSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Bindsource
        SQLDataAdapter.Update(DatabaseDatSet)
        MySqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
    MySqlConn.Dispose()
```

I keep getting error saying that there is a SQL error here '>= ('" & DateTimePicker2 & " ')'

Comment: The syntax of your query is incorrect. Why are you putting the `WHERE` fields in brackets? Also, I believe you need to specify the field name (EventDate) again after the `AND`.

Comment: What is the actual message?  It may not like text being used with math operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, you can either use `between` without `<=` and `>=`(mind symbol sequence in the operators):

```
Dim Query = "select *
             from venuesdb.cost
             where EventDate  between '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'"
```

or specify field each time you specify condition:

```
Dim Query = "select *
             from venuesdb.cost
             where EventDate  >= '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' AND EventDate <= '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `EventDate` in your query. Change your code to this:

```
Dim Query = "Select * From venuesdb.cost where EventDate  >= ('" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "') AND EventDate =< ('" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "')"
```

Also, you should use parameters in your query to avoid SQL-injection attacks. You can read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) SO question.